# Firebird query with string concatenation and like in the where clause doesn't work

Tags: firebird, string-concatenation, sql-like, firebird2.5

I have a users table with first name and last name. I want to find a user for a string like 'clark kent'.
I do this

```sql
SELECT * FROM user WHERE fisrt_name || ' ' || last_name LIKE '%clark kent%'
```

but I don't have any result.
Why? If I search for 'clark' or 'kent' it works.

Comment: Show us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please:  CREATE TABLE, INSERT a record, then the SELECT that works and the SELECT that doesn't.  My guess is that `first_name` is a [space-padded CHAR column](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq237/) so you are actually pattern matching against a constructed value that looks something like this:  `clark[sp][sp][sp][sp]kent[sp][sp][sp][sp]`

Comment: You are right! The fields are char not varchar. Now i clear the fields first_name and last_name with trim(). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
SELECT *
  FROM user
 WHERE TRIM("first_name") || ' ' || TRIM("last_name") LIKE '%clark kent%';
```

Per the OP's comments, the difficulty was that `first_name` and `last_name` were CHAR and not VARCHAR fields, meaning that the fields are space-padded to their length.  That is, the string `'clark'` stored as CHAR(8) is `'clark[sp][sp][sp]'`.

When concatenating the fields together to form a "full name", then, the resulting string had unexpected spaces:  `'clark[sp][sp][sp][sp]kent[sp][sp][sp][sp]'`.

(As an aside, in strict SQL, CHAR columns are rather counter-intuitive.  They *compare* without regard to space padding, but the LIKE operator does not ignore space padding.  See the [Firebird FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq237/).)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
  FROM user
 WHERE upper(fisrt_name) LIKE '%CLARK%'
   and upper(last_name)  LIKE '%KENT%'
```